# Cypress does not open "https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com" . Why it happens?

Tags: redirect, cypress, data.stackexchange.com

I tried to click on that link in `stackexchange.com` at first and received `"Whoops, there is no test to run."` info.
Then tried to directly open the link, it behaves same.
I used `invoke('attr', 'target', '_self')` and `"experimentalSourceRewriting": true` in `cypress.json` But didn't work.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you paste your test to make question clearer?

Comment: `cy.visit('https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com')`

Comment: I mean lines in test before cy.visit